# Insulting Someone

Tags: halacha, bein-adam-lachavero

Would any sources indicate that, if one gave you the permission to verbally insult them because it “makes them happy”, it would be halachically allowed?

Comment: "Permission to insult someone." I do not why someone would even want to do that.

Comment: @Turk Why is that relevant? The rabbis discussed someone who says הכני פצני

Comment: @user6591 Hum, you know that's a good point.

Comment: I read somewhere that some rabbi asked his wife to continuously insult him. So it seems to be allowed.

Comment: @interested Seems pretty absurd to me. Would appreciate if you took the time to find the source of what you've read "somewhere". And OP: Do you really think that such a case exists in this world? Masochism and weird perverted "pleasure through pain and degradation" aren't making anyone truly happy. It's rather a sad outgrowth of something that went rather drastically wrong somewhere along the way in the life of a person. (In my opinion, of course)

Comment: @llja I suppose the reason was to train himself to accept and not reply to abuse. I dont think I can find it. Although if he asked her specially this training wouldnt be much use. I think nevardak also did something similar. I would leave out the makes them happy bit.